# Test if checkbox is checked

Tags: c#, while-loop

### Question

How do I constantly check to see if a checkbox has been checked, then if it is, do something.

If it is un-ticked undo the changes.

### What I've tried

```
 public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            statusCmb.Text = "All";


           while (advancedQueryCb.Checked == true)
           {

                statusCmb.Text = null;
                String SQL = "SELECT * FROM bd;


            }

        }
```

Comment: Instead of constantly checking if a checkbox is checked have you considered subscribing to the [`CheckedChanged`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.checkbox.checkedchanged(v=vs.110).aspx) event? This event will be raised when the checkbox's Checked property value changes and you can perform the desired SQL query. This will obviously work in WinForms and WPF applications but you haven't actually specified whether you are using this technology.

Comment: No didn't know it existed. Will look into it now, thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may subscribe to the [`CheckedChangedEvent`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.checkbox.checkedchanged(v=vs.110).aspx) of the checkbox which will be raised when the value of the `Checked` property changes:

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    statusCmb.Text = "All";
    advancedQueryCb.CheckedChangedEvent += (sender, e) => 
    {
        var checkbox = (CheckBox)sender;
        if (checkbox.Checked)
        {
            // The checkbox has been checked, so you can perform the 
            // necessary logic here
        }
    };
}
```

Answer (score 2):

That's what events are for

```
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        advancedQueryCb.CheckedChanged += advancedQueryCb_CheckedChanged;
    }

    void advancedQueryCb_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        tatusCmb.Text = null;
        String SQL = "SELECT * FROM bd;
    }
```